# Semantic Segmentation Camera in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

I want to add a Semantic Segmentation Camera to my Robot in Gazebo. I have a urdf file in which I have described my robot and all the other sensors such as camera and Lidar. For lidar and camera, there are suitable plugins available.
I want to add same for semantic segmentation camera. Can anyone point me to the plugin for segmentation camera?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is [this tutorial](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/6.0/segmentationcamera_igngazebo.html) what you are looking for?